# Random generator function in Python

Tags: python, random, command, spyder, pythonxy

I have been learning Java since September, but have been given an assignment for a science course by a professor to create a program in Python that will generate a random diameter using a max and minimum value, and 15 random points within this sphere (x, y, z).

I need to make a random number generator that generates a number between 0.0 and 1.0 so I can plug it into my formula to find a random diameter. If the random number is RN, it would be: [(RN*(max-min))+min]

At first I used this random function:

```
from random import*
RN=random():
```

The problem is, this random function is [0.0, 1.0). In other words, it does not include 1.0.
How can I create a function that includes 1.0?

Also, if you don't mind, can you help me with finding the y and z coordinates? I know how to find x.

The formula for the y value is y=+ or - sqrt(r^2-x^2)  (to be randomly generated too).
I would have the x value, which is the result from the random function [0.0-1.0], and the radius which would be half my diameter. I am a complete beginner at Python, how do I initialize my x and y and put the above formula in?

The formula for z is similar, z=+ or - sqrt(-x^2-y^2+r^2)   (to be randomly generated as well)

These are using the formulas for a circle:
radius: r=sqrt(x^2+y^2)
sphere:r=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)

I would be incredibly grateful if you could answer any part of my question, thank you so much for taking the time to read this!!
 **by the way, I am usinHi! I have been learning Java since September, but have been given an assignment for a science course by a professor to create a program in Python that will generate a random diameter using a max and minimum value, and 15 random points within this sphere (x, y, z).

I need to make a random number generator that generates a number between 0.0 and 1.0 so I can plug it into my formula to find a random diameter. If the random number is RN, it would be: [(RN*(max-min))+min]

At first I used this random function:

from random import*
RN=random():

The problem is, this random function is [0.0, 1.0). In other words, it does not include 1.0.
How can I create a function that includes 1.0?

Also, if you don't mind, can you help me with finding the y and z coordinates? I know how to find x.

The formula for the y value is y=+ or - sqrt(r^2-x^2)  (to be randomly generated too).
I would have the x value, which is the result from the random function [0.0-1.0], and the radius which would be half my diameter. I am a complete beginner at Python, how do I initialize my x and y and put the above formula in?

The formula for z is similar, z=+ or - sqrt(-x^2-y^2+r^2)   (to be randomly generated as well)

These are using the formulas for a circle:
radius: r=sqrt(x^2+y^2)
sphere:r=sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2)

I would be incredibly grateful if you could answer any part of my question, thank you so much for taking the time to read this!!!

**by the way, I am using python x,y spyder!

Answer (score 1):

`random.uniform` will give you a uniformly distributed random number between a given minimum and maximum.

Just generate random points and check if they are within the sphere. If they are not, discard them and try again.

```
import math
import random

def generate_points(n_points, min_diameter=0, max_diameter=1):
    diameter = random.uniform(min_diameter, max_diameter)
    radius = diameter / 2
    count = 0
    while count < n_points:
        x, y, z = [random.uniform(-radius, radius) for _ in range(3)]
        distance = math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z)
        if distance <= radius:
            yield (x, y, z)
            count += 1

for x, y, z in generate_points(10):
    print x, y, z
```

Note: this may bias what points are generated. (I'm not sure, it's probably okay actually.) Another approach might be to use polar coordinates, choosing two random angles and a random radius (offset from center).

Here is the math for that approach:

```
theta = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
phi = random.uniform(-math.pi / 2, math.pi / 2)
x = r * cos(theta) * cos(phi)
y = r * sin(phi)
z = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi)
```

See here for more on distribution:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87230/picking-random-points-in-the-volume-of-sphere-with-uniform-probability

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html (this one is about points on the surface of the sphere, so might not be as useful)

Answer (score 1):

**I used this for a random generator and it works, i'm not sure if it's the right one you're looking for but I hope it helps**

```
import random

maths_operator_list=['+','-','*']
maths_operator = random.choice(maths_operator_list)
number_one = random.randint(0,20)
number_two = random.randint(0,20)
correct_answer = 0

print(str(number_one), str(maths_operator), number_two)

if maths_operator == '+':
    correct_answer = number_one + number_two
elif maths_operator == '-':
    correct_answer = number_one - number_two
elif maths_operator == '*':
    correct_answer = number_one * number_two

print(correct_answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

As answer to the random number generator :

```
RN = random.uniform(a, b)
```

Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

As how to initiate x and y, y will be initialize when you set y = to something, it does it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `random.range`

```
random.randrange(-15,15,.1)
```

That will find a number between -15 and 15 that is divisible by 0.1.

Comment: `random.randrange` can only have integer arguments. The better way to do this (in my opinion) is `random.randrange(-150, 150, 1)/10`.